# Not able to login through Multi Attribute when Email is enabled as username in wso2 Identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using Identity server version 6.1, Here if **we enable email as username** in wso2 identity server and **enable multiattribute login**, I'm not able to login through Mobile Number even after adding the mobile claim in Allowed Attribute Claim List under multi attribute login of Identity provider. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have faced has been already reported in https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/14930

With the introduction of the MultiAttribute Login feature in the product, a user gets the flexibility over controlling username and configure any attribute as his preferred login identifier.
This feature cleared up the actual requirement of email as a username feature in previous IS versions where email is considered as an immutable attribute.

So without enabling email as username feature, as a workaround, you can configure email and mobile as login identifiers. You have to mark both claims as unique claims as well.
If you want to keep the user's username also as an email, change the regex pattern of username claim